# What if a Drools rule tries to modify a non-existing object

Tags: drools, rule

Currently, we are using Drools rules to work with java object which are persisted with hibernate.

Let's say we have a Java object persisted by hibernate and insert this object into the working memory. Then in some rule we try to modify the fact - in the working memory as well as the Java object. Now assume the Java object is no longer valid/does no longer exist at that point. While we would normally try to inform the Drools engine about the changes, let's assume we couldn't do so in this case - possibly because of some error or a rollback immediately after the creation.

Does Drools notify us about objects who were to be altered in a rule but do no longer exist? I would suppose this is not possible. What options could we use to get around such problems?